# Get output of shell command in Haxe

Tags: bash, haxe

In Haxe, is there a method in the Sys class (or some other class) that returns the output of a shell command (for example, the command "ls"), or will I need to implement this method myself for each target language? I'd like to find a method for invoking shell commands that works with every Haxe target language.

Comment: It would be possible to implement this method separately in each target language (using conditional compilation), but it would be better if this functionality was available in Haxe's standard API. Is it part of the Haxe standard API?

Comment: After a lot of searching, I found this relevant thread (which appears to contain the answer to my question!): http://haxe.org/forum/thread/3395#nabble-td5537667

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your own comment contain the answer, which is:

```
var output = new sys.io.Process("ls", []).stdout.readAll().toString();
```

Comment: Will I need to import any additional modules to get this to work?

Comment: No. Just note that `sys.io.Process` is only available on sys platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Or the cross platform way: `sys.FileSystem.readDirectory('')`

It might also be faster, because it doesn't invoke an extra process.

Comment: This is a useful answer, but I think it should be posted as an answer to a separate question (since it is relevant to one specific use case - getting the output of `ls`).

Comment: Also, can you explain why the other way of doing it isn't cross-platform? (Does `var output = new sys.io.Process("ls", []).stdout.readAll().toString();` produce different results, depending on the operating system?)

Comment: Also, is it possible to detect the operating system in Haxe (in a cross-language way?)

Comment: @AndersonGreen: [Sys.systemName()](http://haxe.org/api/sys) will give you the OS name.

Comment: @AndersonGreen `ls` will not work on microsoft plattforms afaik, also `ls` was given as an example.